# ASP.NET - Ability to Export CSV/excel to Multiple sheets?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export, devexpress

I was wondering if anyone has a solution to be able to export data into excel in multiple sheets... As of now I only know how to export multiple objects into a single sheet!

I am using Devexpress exporter?? Seems like they don't support this, I can go with a generic solution as well?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Epplus ?

http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439

I used this in winforms application and it's great. It only does xlsx files though - ie Excel 2007 onwards.

andrew

Answer (score 0):

filepath should probably be server.mappath() as generated excel shoul first be saved  in server path and can be allowed to download.
Add reference Excel and add namespace "Using Excel".

```
   public void Export(DataSet ds, string filePath)
    {
        string data = null;
        string columnName = null;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        //Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Excel.Range range;

        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        //xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);


        for (int l = 0; l < ds.Tables.Count; l++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(l + 1);                
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1:D1", Type.Missing).Merge(Type.Missing);
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").Font.Bold = true;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells.Font.Name = "Courier New";

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[l].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {


                for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[l].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    columnName = ds.Tables[l].Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, j + 1] = columnName;
                    data = ds.Tables[l].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 5, j + 1] = data;
                }
            }
        }

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(filePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        // kill all excel processes
        Process[] pros = Process.GetProcesses();
        for (int p = 0; p < pros.Length; p++)
        {
            if (pros[p].ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("excel"))
            {
                pros[p].Kill();
                break;
            }
        }

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem early last year. Eventually I was able to hack my way into automate generation of a .xlt Excel file with multiple spreadsheets (which are actually webpages) that can be accepted by Excel.

I know it's not pretty, but it worked for me. If you decide to try it, let me know if it works for you too.

Output the followings (you can adjust to have any number of sheets you want):

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Document-Type: Workbook
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_01CB53EC.0FFDF540"

------=_NextPart_01CB53EC.0FFDF540
Content-Location: file:///C:/CE594991/Book1.htm
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"

<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>

<link id=3D"shLink" href=3D"Book1_files/Sheet1.htm">
<link id=3D"shLink" href=3D"Book1_files/Sheet2.htm">
<link id=3D"shLink" href=3D"Book1_files/Sheet3.htm">

<xml>
 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
    <x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name>
    <x:WorksheetSource HRef=3D"Book1_files/Sheet1.htm"/>
   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
    <x:Name>Sheet2</x:Name>
    <x:WorksheetSource HRef=3D"Book1_files/Sheet2.htm"/>
   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
    <x:Name>Sheet3</x:Name>
    <x:WorksheetSource HRef=3D"Book1_files/Sheet3.htm"/>
   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
 </x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml>
</head>

</html>
```

For each page, output:

```
------=_NextPart_01CB53EC.0FFDF540
Content-Location: file:///C:/CE594991/Book1_files/{ your sheet name }".htm
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html>
{ your stuffs }
</html>
```

End for loop

```
------=_NextPart_01CB53EC.0FFDF540
Content-Location: file:///C:/CE594991/Book1_files/filelist.xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"

<xml xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
 <o:MainFile HRef=3D"../Book1.htm"/>
 <o:File HRef=3D"Sheet1.htm"/>
 <o:File HRef=3D"Sheet2.htm"/>
 <o:File HRef=3D"Sheet3.htm"/>
</xml>
------=_NextPart_01CB53EC.0FFDF540--
```

In your code, set response buffer to false, content type to "application/vnd.ms-excel" and add the header "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename={ your file name }". Note there must be no line breaks before the first line of your output file.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Devexpress exporter?? Seems like they don't support this, I
>   can go with a generic solution as well?

Are you trying the [XlsxExportOptions.ExportMode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingXlsxExportOptions_ExportModetopic) property? The [SingleFilePageByPage](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingXlsxExportModeEnumtopic) export mode allows you to export a document page-by-page to multiple sheets within the same XLSX file. Please also look at the the following article:[How to export a report to the different sheets in the XLS file](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1352.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the http://www.devexpress.com/example=E2440 regarding your request.

It seems that it is exactly you are looking for.